# Why is my quick smoke simulation lagging on a Ryzen 7-3800x? Blender 2.82(just downloaded for pc)

Tags: physics

Hi I recently built a pc which has a Ryzen 7 3800x which should be a pretty solid CPU for blender (i thought judging by the benchmarks) but when I try to playback a simple smoke and fire simulation my fps is around 13fps @30(resolution divisions) and 1.8 @60. I was able to run the smoke simulation on my laptop no problem with no lag and it has a I7-7700k processor, I got 15 fps @60. At this point I'm just really confused with what is going on and why I'm having fps issues running a non complex smoke and fire simulation on my ryzen cpu. I left everything on the stock setting, just changed the cache from modular to playback. Id be really grateful for some clarity on my issue, is my ryzen cpu just that much worse then my intel or are there some settings I need to change?
enter image description here

[image: screenshot of my physics settings]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem with version 2.91 and I found that installing blender version 2.80 did the trick. Not sure if there's a way of getting a full 24 fps with your specs in the latest version but thats how I was able to get a better frame rate. Here's the link I used for the download:

https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/

Hope it helps, and if you somehow find a solution for this with the latest version I'd love to hear it.